70s horror movie with deja vu / “it was all a dream”
I’m pretty sure this this movie was released some time between 1971 and 1976. It may have been a segment of a gallery movie.
The story starts with an alarm clock going off. A hand reaches over and turns it off, inadvertently knocking a pencil off the nightstand. The people waking up are a man/woman couple (American I believe - but maybe English) that is all excited about doing something that day - seeing a new house?, visiting a relative? - something. Any way, they get ready for the day, eat breakfast, drive in the car, having a pleasant conversation all the while.
What happens next is the “horror” part of the movie which is actually the bulk of the story. Sorry, I forget all the details here :) Anyway, they end up at some house and really horrible things happen to them. Then, right when something REALLY bad is about to happen…
BOOM
Suddenly, we see the beginning of the movie again. The screen shows the alarm clock going off. The same hand reaches over and turns it off, inadvertently knocking a pencil off the nightstand (again). One of the two people (the wife, I believe) knows about everything that we as the audience have just seen. She is somehow compelled to participate in the activities and speak the conversation we saw at the beginning of the movie, but we can tell she is getting increasingly freaked out. She may even express grave doubts about continuing with their plans for the day, with her husband poo-pooing her to not be silly. So, they get in the car (again) and start driving (again) - all pretty much the same as the beginning of the movie, except once they are under way, the wife freaks out, grabs the steering wheel and causes them to have a fatal car crash. THE END :)

Was the movie in black and white?

The movie was definitely in color.

It sounds a little like "Necromancy" with Orson Welles, which has that same "I woke up and then my dream started to happen" ending.  But I don't recall the woman (Pamela Franklin, I think) causing an accident. However, I haven't seen it in a long time, so it's possible.

If you think this is the correct answer, add links and a plot summary.

Thanks so much for taking the time to help me figure this out. After watching several bits of Orson Welles' Necromancy at DailyMotion.com I am sad to say this is not the movie. The one that I am remembering featured a young couple mid to late twenties I'd say, and had more of a 'modern' feel to it.

@Janet
Necromancy IS the correct movie!
When I tried to find a copy of Necromancy on the web to view, I must have found something that was mismarked the first time because what I found was a movie that was set in the 19th century. I just found a copy posted on YouTube and this is definitely the movie I was thinking of!
I am so sorry it tool so long for you to get the credit you deserve.
